# Determine for which values of a the equation represents a circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x^2+y^2+ax+16=0$

Determine for which value of $a$ the equation represents a circle.

How would one tackle such a problem?
I have no experience with these types of questions.

Comment: Complete the square such that $x^2$ and $ax$ both result from the expansion of $(x-\beta)^2$ for some $\beta$ that depends on $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To become the equation of a circle, you need to get rid of $ax$, and this is a pretty standard completing the square problem:

$$x^2+ax+(\frac{a}{2})^2+y^2+16= (\frac{a}{2})^2$$

or

$$(x+\frac{a}{2})^2+y^2= \frac{a^2}{4}-16$$

This is the equation of a circle if and only if the RHS is positive. Solve now

$$\frac{a^2}{4}-16 >0$$.

Comment: You light me. Thanks for noting my mistake (+1).

Comment: @BabakSorouh no problem, we all do mistakes sometimes ;)

Comment: Thank you sir, I understand.

Answer (score 1):

We complete the square to get:
$$\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^{2}+y^{2}-\frac{a^{2}}{4}+16=0$$
Thus $$\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^{2}+y^{2}=\frac{a^2}{4}-16$$
Which is a circle with centre $(-a/2,0)$ and radius $\frac{a^{2}}{4}-16$. This only makes sense when $\frac{a^{2}}{4}-16>0$, so $a^{2}>64$, giving $a>8$ or $a<-8$.